# Where are the details of 'Pathname Expansion' and 'Brace Expansion' in man page?

Tags: bash, man, set

I was trying to go through a man page with a calm mind for the first time, and I hit a frustration already 2 minutes down the road.

```
$ man set
 nocaseglob
                      If set, bash matches filenames in a case-insensitive fashion  when  performing  pathname
                      expansion (see Pathname Expansion above)
...
-B      The  shell performs brace expansion (see Brace Expansion above).  This is on by default.
```

These few extracted line from that man page shows 'see Pathname Expansion above' and 'see Brace Expansion above'. But I searched the entire document, and this is no such heading/sub-heading. I believe, it might be explained in theory but not put as a topic in itself. Am I right? or is there any place I can get info on these?

fyi.

```
$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: `/Pathname Expansion` or `/Brace Expansion` jump to the heading.

Comment: @cuonglm, Yes, i tried the same. Says 'Pattern not found'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even the Bash 2.0  man page contains a section on *Brace Expansion*. From the archives of FreeBSD, the manpage of [`bash (1)` for CentOS 3.9](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bash&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=CentOS%20Linux%2Fi386%203.9&arch=default&format=html):

```
Brace Expansion
   Brace expansion is a mechanism by which arbitrary strings may be gener-
   ated.  This mechanism is similar to pathname expansion, but  the  file-
   names generated need not exist.  Patterns to be brace expanded take the
   form of an optional preamble, followed by a series  of  comma-separated
   strings  between  a pair of braces, followed by an optional postscript.
   The preamble is prefixed to each string contained  within  the  braces,
   and the postscript is then appended to each resulting string, expanding
   left to right.
...
GNU Bash-2.05b           2002 July 15                  BASH(1)
```

I suppose you simply need to search more.

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks. So it's in the `man bash` and not in `man set` where i found the reference to it.

Comment: @mtk I suppose what you see as the manpage of set is actually an extract from the manpage of bash. Or the output of `help -m set`. Do you have any aliases defined for man?

Answer (score 0):

The man page says search above. This you can do by typing <kbd>?</kbd> (to search backward, followed by `Pathname Expansion` and hitting <kbd>N</kbd> to search further in the previous direction, until you find the definition.